# How to check does image set in ImageView

Tags: android

How can i check does image set in ImageView or no, exists standard methods?

```
ImageView imgV;
imgV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if(imgV != set)  ///!!!!! 
  imgV.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
else 
  imgV.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish by calling `setImageBitmap(null)`? If you're trying to make it such that the `ImageView` has no bitmap and thus doesn't appear, you should use the `getVisibility()` and `setVisibility()` methods in the `View` class.  I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but

```
ImageView imgV;
imgV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if(imgV.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {  //or use View.GONE 
  imgV.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
  imgV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
  imgV.setImageBitmap(null);
  imgV.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //or use View.GONE
}
```

Comment: hey i want to ask samething but different.i wanna clear the image after its set.i have problem.i am setting the image after it come from w/s when i vl click on next then in w/s image is not coming but i vl seen old image so how can i clear?help me

Answer (score 0):

**You can check ImageView by,**

```
  if(imageView.getDrawable==null)
   {

            //imageview is set
   }

 else
  {
           //imageview is set
  }
```